# What is the classpath of flywayDb when using Gradle?

Tags: database, gradle, database-migration, flyway

I am trying to create a simple gradle project that should just be used to migrate a database using flywayDb using migration scripts that are stored within JAR files in another directory. This directory is not related to the gradle build in any way. It is created and populated using another mechanism within the project.

The (at least for me) obvious script didn't work:

```
[...]

// flyway plugin
apply plugin: 'org.flywaydb.flyway'

// dependencies
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: '/workspace/WEB-INF/lib', include: '*.jar')
}

// flyway configuration
flyway {
    [...]
    locations = [ 'classpath:/META-INF/db' ]
}
```

When calling the flyway migrate task all I get is

```
Unable to resolve location classpath:META-INF/db
```

and nothing is migrated. If I extract the JAR files and use a `filesystem` location it works fine. So I guess that the classpath that flyway is using doesn't include the JAR files.

This brings me to my question: What classpath is flyway using for the search for database scripts? And how can I add simple JAR files from the file system to that?

Edit:

Complete build.gradle after comment:

```
// add JDBC drivers (for flyway) and flyway itself to classpath
buildscript {
        repositories {
                maven {
                        url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
                }
        }
        dependencies {
                classpath group: 'gradle.plugin.com.boxfuse.client', name: 'gradle-plugin-publishing', version: '5.0.7'
                classpath group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.42'
        }
}

// flyway plugin
apply plugin: 'org.flywaydb.flyway'

// configurations
configurations {
        flywayClasspath
}

// dependencies
dependencies {
        flywayClasspath fileTree(dir: '/workspace/WEB-INF/lib', include: '*.jar')
        flywayClasspath files('/workspace/WEB-INF/classes')
}

// get needed data for connection
def dbPassword = System.getenv('MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD')
def dbName = System.getenv('PROJECTNAME')

// flyway configuration
flyway {
        configurations = [ 'flywayClasspath' ]
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/${dbName}?rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Europe/Berlin&useSSL=false"
        driver = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
        user = 'root'
        password = dbPassword
        locations = [ "classpath:/META-INF/db/mysql" ]
        table = 'schema_version'
        outOfOrder = true
        ignoreMissingMigrations = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see from the [source code](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/master/flyway-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/gradle/task/AbstractFlywayTask.java) that there's a `configurations` property. I'm guessing by default it uses the buildscript classpath. If you want compiled classes on flyway's classpath you could do something like

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'x.y.flyway'

configurations {
    flyway
}
dependencies {
    flyway sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
flyway.configurations = ['flyway']
flywayMigrate.dependsOn compileJava
```

Comment: Thanks but `configurations` seems to be read-only: `Cannot set the value of read-only property 'configurations' for root project 'database' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

Comment: I can see the public property on the extension object [here](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/master/flyway-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/gradle/FlywayExtension.java#L292). Judging by the error message I'm guessing you're not setting inside a `flyway { ... }` closure.

Comment: It is within the `flyway` closure. I updated the initial question with the complete `build.gradle`. `flyway` for configuration name didn't work (maybe reserved by task/plugin). Therefore i named it `flywayClasspath`.

Comment: Ah, perhaps `flyway.configurations` is clashing with `project.configurations` which would explain the error message. See my update using `flyway.configurations = x`

Comment: This causes `Could not set unknown property 'configurations' for object of type org.flywaydb.gradle.FlywayExtension.`. If I try to set it on `flywayMigration` instead of `flyway` it causes the same but with type `org.flywaydb.gradle.task.FlywayMigrateTask`

Comment: Perhaps you're on an old version of the plugin

Comment: I am using `5.0.7` which is the current release. But according to the source the `configurations` were added 3 months ago which is newer than the current release. So I guess this is not part of any release yet. I am now using the flyway command line tool. That just works fine. Thanks for your help anyway.